# Loop bootstrap object display

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I have a small problem of CSS and I do not understand where it can come ... I would like to display 3 images per lines under which I can come out of my info base. But nothing goes as planned. Could someone unblock me? I do not know where I made my mistake.
My code :

```
{% extends 'index.html.twig' %}

 {% block body %}
<div id="startchange">
    <div class="portfolio-item">

    <section id="objets">
        <div class ="title">
            <p class="titre">List client</p>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            {% for client in clients%}

                <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-3">

                    <img class="img-responsive img-circle" src="img/logos/mario.png">
                    <div class="description">
                        <p class="nom"> Surname : </p>
                        <p class="type"> {{client.surname}}</p>

                        <p class="nom"> First name : </p>
                        <p class="type"> {{client.firstname}}</p>

                    </div>

                </div>


            {%endfor%}
        </div>
    </section>
    </div>
</div>



{% endblock %}
```

The view with 4 objects : 
[List of 4 objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mG9Fj.png)

The view with 0 object : [0 object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDJuK.png)

It seems that all the objects go in the same square of the line and not in 4 different boxes I do not understand why ... An idea?

Comment: I have found a solution !

Comment: Which is what ...